# How to give multiple variables as input to a script from one script run remotely

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I created a Bash Shell script on Gnu/Linux, that does an ssh from one server to a bunch of other servers, and runs netcat command for a bunch of IPs.

This is the script that connects to other servers via SSH:

```
*read -p "Enter the instant stack host[s]: " hosts
read -p "Enter the list of destinations [IP]: " dest_list
read -p "Enter the port # associated with the destination: " port
for h in $hosts
do
                scp ./connectivityTest.sh @$h:/var/tmp/
               ssh user@$h . /var/tmp/connectivityTest.sh "$dest_list" "$port"
done*
```

This is the script that runs the netcat command:

```
*echo "Working on `hostname` to check connectivity for following end points"
echo $1
echo $2
dest_list=`echo "$1"`
port=`echo "$2"`
echo $dest_list
        for d in $dest_list
        do
                echo "Endpoint checked:  $d"
                        nc -v -i 1 -w 5 $d $port
        done
exit*
```

When I give just single IP [end point] to run, the script runs fine:

```
*Enter the instant stack host[s]: host1.com
 Enter the list of destinations [IP]: **test.ip1.com**
Enter the port # associated with the destination: 443
connectivityTest.sh                                                                                                                                        100%  520     1.8MB/s   00:00
##############################################################
Working on host1 to check connectivity for following end points
##############################################################
test.ip1.com 
443
test.ip1.com 
Endpoint checked:  test.ip1.com
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ip1:443.
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (1000 ms).*
```

However when I give multiple end points, the script takes the second IP/end point as the port number.

```
*Enter the instant stack host[s]: host1.com 
Enter the list of destinations [IP]: **test.ip1.com test.ip2.com**
Enter the port # associated with the destination: 443
connectivityTest.sh                                                                                                                                        100%  520     1.8MB/s   00:00
##############################################################
Working on host1 to check connectivity for following end points
##############################################################
test.ip1.com
**test.ip2.com**
test.ip1.com
Endpoint checked:  test.ip1.com
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
**Ncat: Invalid port number "test.ip2.com". QUITTING.***
```

Also this happens only when the script is run via SSH. If I run the script directly on the server, it works fine with multiple IPs. It is obvious that something is not right at this level:

```
*ssh user@$h . /var/tmp/connectivityTest.sh "$dest_list" "$port"*
```

Then I found this work around. I added the input variables under single quote:

```
*ssh user@$h . /var/tmp/ "'$dest_list'" "'$port'"*
```

It works with multiple IPs now:

```
*Enter the instant stack host[s]: host1.com
Enter the list of destinations [IP]: **test.ip1.com test.ip2.com test.ip3.com test.ip4.com**
Enter the port # associated with the destination: 443
connectivityTest.sh                                                                                                                                        100%  525     1.5MB/s   00:00
##############################################################
Working on host1 to check connectivity for following end points
##############################################################
test.ip1.com test.ip2.com 
443
test.ip1.com test.ip2.com 
Endpoint checked:  test.ip1.com
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ip1:443.
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (1000 ms).
Endpoint checked:  test.ip2.com
Ncat: Version 7.50 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Connected to ip2:443.
Ncat: Idle timeout expired (1000 ms).*
```

Even though I resolved it, I am not sure how the **single quote** makes the difference between running **the script locally vs running it via ssh**.
Also how the **single quote** makes the difference between running **the script with multiple inputs vs single input**.

Any insights will be helpful.
Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you

```
ssh user@$h . /var/tmp/connectivityTest.sh '$dest_list' '$port'
```

?

If it works the same as your workaround, the problem is which system your variables are being expanded on (local or remote).